# How can I pass Xcode Cloud environment variables to Xcode project when building the project using Xcode Cloud?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode-cloud

I am tasked with passing environment variables from the Xcode Cloud server to the Xcode project while building it with Xcode Cloud. When I build the app locally, I fetch environment variables from the scheme.

[image: Accessing environment variables from the scheme when building locally]

Then in the codebase, this is how environment variables are accessed:

`ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["API_KEY"]`

This is where the environment variables are set in the Xcode Cloud. I right-clicked on the workflow in the Cloud tab found in the Report Navigator of the Xcode and selected "Edit Workflow":

[image]

I don't know how to write a code so that when the Xcode project is built using the Xcode Cloud, environment variables can be injected and used.

There was not much that I could have tried because I am new at DevOp stuff and resources regarding this topic was so limited.

Answer (score 1):

Environment variables set in Xcode Cloud will be available during *build time*. For example you can access those variables in a "Build Phase Scripts".

These variables are not available during *runtime*.
In order to make them available at runtime, you could use a Xcode Cloud pre-xcodebuild script to update an Info.plist or some other file you can access.
See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73062195/how-to-use-custom-xcode-cloud-environment-variables).